# Convert sql query to entity framework linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query

```
select  distinct (case 
    when object like'%service%' then (object)
    when  host like '%service%' then (host) 
    when  class like '%service%' then (class) 
    when  parameter like '%service%' then (parameter) 
 end), (case 
    when object like'%service%' then 'objet'
    when  class like '%service%' then 'objet_class' 
    when  host like '%service%' then 'host' 
     when  parameter like '%service%' then 'parametre' 
 end) from [dbo].[full] where(object <>'NULL' and class<>'NULL' and parameter<>'NULL' and host <>'NULL')
```

I would like to know how to write in entity framework linq query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Contains("x")` should be translated to `LIKE '%x%'`.

`? :` should be translated to `CASE WHEN`.

```
var q = from f in dbContext.Full 
where !f.object.Equals("NULL") && !f.class.Equals("NULL") && !f.parameter.Equals("NULL") && !f.host.Equals("NULL")
select new {
     f.object.Contains("service") ? f.object :
     f.host.Contains("service") ? f.host :
     f.class.Contains("service") ? f.class :
     f.parameter.Contains("service") ? f.parameter :
     null,
     f.object.Contains("service") ? "object" :
     f.host.Contains("service") ? "host" :
     f.class.Contains("service") ? "object_class" :
     f.parameter.Contains("service") ? "parameter" :
     "N/A"
};
```

Comment: That worked fine but when there is no value "service" in some column he gives me an exeception.

Comment: What exception on what line? When you call `q.ToList()` for example?

Comment: I called .Distinct().ToList(), and if a column is null (doesnt have any service value) it  sends an exception

Comment: Perhaps you would like to check instead `!f.object.Equals("NULL")` (string value "NULL") the null value like this `where f.object!=null && ...` Those are two different conditions.

Comment: I've noticed when i do more than 3 conditions (if else if else ) i get that error

Comment: And what exception it is?

Comment: It's solved, i had an issue with data their so millions of rows and query couldn't handle it but when i've limited number of rows it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var temp = 
        from f in context.full
        where f.object != "NULL" && f.class != "NULL" && f.parameter != "NULL"
        select new {
            service =   f.object.Contains("service") ? f.object :
                        f.host.Contains("service") ? f.host :
                        f.class.Contains("service") ? f.class :
                        f.parameter.Contains("service") ? f.parameter,
            serviceType = f.object.Contains("service") ? "object" :
                        f.host.Contains("service") ? "host" :
                        f.class.Contains("service") ? "object_class" :
                        f.parameter.Contains("service") ? "parameter"
        }
```